# Chrome WebGL performance wildly inconsistent?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, webgl

```js
function render(time, scene) {
    if (useFramebuffer) {
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, scene.fb);
    }

    gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    renderScene(scene);

    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    if (useFramebuffer) {
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        copyFBtoBackBuffer(scene.fb);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
        render(time, scene);
    });
}
```

I'm not able to share the exact code I use, but a mockup will illustrate my point.

I'm rendering a fairly complex scene and am also doing some ray tracing in WebGL. I've noticed two very strange performance issues.

1) Inconsistent frame rate between runs.
Sometimes, when the page starts the first ~100 frames render in 25ms, then it suddenly drops to 45ms, without any user input or changes to the scene. I'm not updating any buffer or texture data in a frame, only shader uniforms. When this happens the GPU memory stays constant.

2) Rendering to the default framebuffer is slower than using an extra pass.
If I render to a created frambuffer and then blit to the HTML canvas (the default framebuffer), I get 10% performance increase. So in the code snippet, if `useFramebuffer == true` performance is gained, which seems very counter intuitive.

**Edit 1:**

Due to changes in requirements, the scene will always be rendered to a framebuffer and then copied to the canvas. This makes question 2) a non-issue.

**Edit 2:**

System specs of the PC this was tested on:

- OS: Win 10
- CPU: Intel i7-7700
- Nvidia GTX 1080
- RAM: 16 GB

**Edit 3:**

I profiled the scene using chrome:tracing. The first ~100-200 frames render 16.6ms.

[image: The fast part]

Then it starts dropping frames.
[image: The slow part]

I'll try profiling everything with timer queries, but I'm afraid that each render actually takes the same amount of time, and buffer swap will randomly take twice as long.

Another thing I noticed is that this starts happening when I use Chrome for a while. When the problems start, clearing the browser cache or killing the Chrome process don't help, only a system reboot does.

Is it possible that Chrome is throttling the GPU on a whim?

P.S.
The frame times changed because of some optimizations, but the core problem persists.

Comment: What happens if you store `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` in variables, as opposed to re-reading them each frame?

Comment: @emackey Tried it and it does nothing, and why would it? Aren't `width` and `height` just canvas attributes?

Comment: What type of graphics card do you have?

Comment: I've added the full system spec

Comment: Try profiling the scene using this method: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/games/abouttracing/

Comment: For the 10% perf increase in fb vs framebuffer try turning off antialiasing on the canvas (`getContext('webgl', {antialias: false})`. note: I'm assuming the fb is the same dimensions as the canvas. If not that would be a difference. For the drop, you claim memory is not changing but is the view changing, the camera moving, objects rotating or moving, or is everything 100% static?

Comment: @gman I turned off the AA and nothing happens. By the looks of the render it was off by default. The dimensions of the FBs are the same.
The scene is 100% static, nothing moves, all of the uniforms stay the same each frame (VP matrix, all of the model matrices, all shading data, everything...)

Comment: Maybe your gpu is throttling itself due to heat?

Comment: Hmm, very interesting point. I'll try something else performance intensive.

Comment: Seems like it isn't, the GPU temperature stays low and other GPU intensive apps don't exhibit same behavior (tested on some shadertoy 3D fractals).